# Javascript/Ajax/PHP Form Validation Error

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, validation

I have a form which is for checking whether or not an author is on my database (bookshop website) before allowing a new one to be entered.

This part works perfectly and authors are found and alerted to the user but when an entry is okay to submit it will not submit...

It merely does nothing. The code below is the checker and then below that is the submit function which is not working...
Basically if validate author is fine then it should submit but at the moment it is not. I have used a similar method for another form on the site and it works but this page has multiple forms on it so it may be an issue?

```
var author = $("#author");
var authortext = $("#authortext");          
var authorForm = $("#addauthor");

//Author Validation
        function validateAuthor()
        {
            author.css('border', '');
            if (author.val().length == 0)
            {
                author.css('border', '2px solid red');
                authortext.text("Please enter an author.");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "authorcheck.php",
                   data: 'author='+ author.val(),

                   //Stops the query being cached.
                   cache: false,
                   //The function when query accepted. 
                   success: function(result)
                   {
                        if (result == 1)
                        {
                            author.css('border', '2px solid red');
                            authortext.text("Author has been added already.");
                            return false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            authortext.text("Correct entry.");
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }



        //Forms are submitted if no errors or blank values are found. The server side checks are still done later if the user has javascript disabled. 
        authorForm.submit(function()
        {
            if (validateAuthor())
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: are `author` and `authortext` global variables?

Comment: Sorry they are above this code and defined as the id tags from the form. Will edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

use `data: { author: author.val(); }`

Comment: That line stopped the rest of it working. The ajax checker and validation works it just will not submit when the form is correct. The .submit() function is where things are not working.

Thanks though!